# How can I include Google font in Kentico Email template?

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am trying to add google font Lato but not getting success

I tried to include google font in my email template via Kentico CMS but that's only shows in the preview mode that font url is included successfully. But as I get email in my Outlook 365 that shows that my desired font url is not there. 
Please help

Add the following in the start of my email template from CMS:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css" id="ignore">
    tr td { padding: 0; margin: 0;border-spacing: 0; }
    a{text-decoration: none;    text-decoration-color: transparent;}
</style>
    </head>
  <body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a question for Kentico or asp.net, instead this is a very general e-mail question and how e-mail displays depends on the implementation of e-mail client (gmail, outlook and so on...).

This is a huge topic by itself, but start by looking at https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/making-custom-font-stacks-work-in-outlook-update/ and https://www.mailigen.com/blog/grab-attention-with-google-web-fonts-in-email-newsletters/